# Mouse cursor disappeared after upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 11.10, 12.04

I was running Ubuntu 11.10, and everything was fine.  I decides to upgraded to 12.04.  Once the upgrade was done, and I rebooted my machine, my mouse cursor is no where to be found.  What could be the issue?

Comment: what is your output of `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf | grep Identifier` ? and also mention what moouse you are using?

Comment: If you are unsure of how to type the commands you need, open Terminal from the unity launcher panel and type the command there. If you want to copy and paste the command, you must paste it using right-click, paste as terminal ignores the key combo for paste.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer.Unplug your mouse and plug it again.It should be working.If it does not works then please specify your computer's make and model

Answer (score 0):

Initially I did not have an xorg.conf file so the above comment to

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf | grep Identifier
```

did not work.

For those with AMD/ATI cards, download and install the latest AMD Catalyst driver. The installer was all covered in black bars for me so I used the screenshots here: http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-1112-linux.html as a guide.

Once the installer finishes, run

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

and reboot. In my case, with the drivers and a xorg.conf file, I can finally see a cursor.